# How to prevent the instantiation of class in python based on parameters passed in?

Tags: python, class, object

Lets say I have a class Vector2D that take x and y components. Because I have no interest in vectors with both components equal to zero, I want to prevent the object with both parameters passed equal to zero from being created in the first place and return None instead.

Comment: You should raise a `ValueError` or other suitable exception, instead, that makes it clear just why a zero vector is a problem.  If you returned None (which can't be done via `__init__()`, you have to use `__new__()` to return something other than an instance of the class being instantiated), the caller would get a completely meaningless error when they try to use the vector.

Comment: I see your point. However, I can handle None valued objects. If I raise a error I would have to use try-except to not break execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rename your class to `RealVector2D` and replace it with a new function:

```
def Vector2D(x, y):
    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        return None
    return RealVector2D(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a factory function to verify that your parameters are not zero, thn return an instance of `Vector2D`, or raise an Error:

As mentioned in the comments by @jasonsharper, returning None is not a good idea, better to return an explicit error.

```
class NullVectorError(ValueError):
    pass


def make_non_null_vector(x: float, y: float) -> vector2D:
    if x and y:
        return Vector2D(x, y)
    raise NullVectorError('the parameters x:{x}, and y:{y}, cannot be both equal to zero')
```